# socket.broadcast.emit socket io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I tried the example chat application at socket.io, and that is worked fine. When I tried socket.broadcast.emit() function, it not worked.
Could anyone help me in that problem?
It is maybe a little bug, but I had waste an hour with it.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.broadcast.emit('New participant connected.'); //DO NOT SEND ANY MESSAGE

    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){

        io.emit('chat message', msg);

    });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: How did you test? AFAIK, `socket.broadcast.emit()` emits a message to all connected sockets _except_ the originating one, so if you are testing with only one client the message won't show up.

Comment: I've opened a firefox and a chrome too(in the same time).'New participant connected' is nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that you're not listening to the *"New participant connected."* event in your clients.

Try this:

```
// server
socket.broadcast.emit('broadcast', 'New participant connected.');

// client
socket.on('broadcast', m => console.log('Received broadcast:', m));
```